# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," with react.js and promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, compiler-errors

I am new in react, I am following a tutorial in udemy, getting the error:

```
 Line 45:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  43 |     TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id).then(() =>
  44 |       this.setState({ message: `Delete of ${id} successfull` })
> 45 |         this.refreshTodo()
     |         ^
  46 |       
  47 |     );
  48 |   }
```

The TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id) deletes an item in the list using a web service, this is the whole TodoDataService module looks like:

```
import Axios from "axios";

class TodoDataService {
  retrieveAllTodos(username) {
    return Axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/users/${username}/todos`);
  }

  deleteTodo(username, id) {
    return Axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/users/${username}/todos/${id}`);
  }

  updateTodo(username, id) {
    return Axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/users/${username}/todos/${id}`);
  }
}

export default new TodoDataService();
```

I am not sure if the tutorial could be too old and the syntax might have change since there or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. `TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id)` returns a promise and you are calling then and passing a closure. However, your closure isn't syntactically valid because it has multiple lines of code but omits the open and close brance.

You should have:

```js
TodoDataService.deleteTodo(username, id).then(() => {
  this.setState({ message: `Delete of ${id} successful` });
  this.refreshTodo();
});
```

If you have a closure that is a single line, it doesn't need braces and it will return the value. For example:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
> add(1, 2)
< 3
```

It's a single line and returns the value 1. However, if you have multiple lines then you need to use braces and explicitly return the value. So this is syntactically valid but isn't logically correct because it doesn't return the result of the addition.

```
const brokenAdd = (a, b) => {
  a + b;
};
> brokenAdd(1, 2)
< undefined
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this worked. I am still new at these other languages.